# magento 1.9 How to change css only for my Brasilian shop throught store configuration system.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml, stores

I have a multiple stores. In one of my stores (Brasilian) i want to remove the bulletpoints from an  on the registration page. Somehow I need to do that via store configuration system.xml file, but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: please descirbe your problem. we not understand what ou want

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a multiple stores. In one of my stores (Brasilian) i want to remove the bulletpoints from an <ul> on the registration page. Somehow I need to do that via store configuration system.xml file, but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Hey this css changes can be done using unique class for your Brazilian store you just need to check on which store you are if on  Brazilian then you can add class only for this store using jQuery and can use it for your design changes.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamKhandelwal, but the requirements are not to use jquery and not to check in the template. I have to do it using system.xml or local.xml